# Using break after default in switch statement when default not at end

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

In a w3schools [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) on switch statements, it says:

> If default is not the last case in the switch block, remember to end
>   the default case with a break.

However, as that tutorial also states:

> When JavaScript reaches a break keyword, it breaks out of the switch
>   block.

So if you have a default with break at the beginning of a switch statement, why wouldn't the default always be executed and the block immediately exited by the interpreter? The interpreter doesn't read the items in the switch statement in order?

Comment: Because the `default:` case is only used if none of the other cases match.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the tutorial states

> The `default` keyword specifies the code to run if there is no `case` match

The position of the `default` keyword doesn't matter, the cases after it will be tested before executing the code in the `default` case. If one of those cases match, its code will be executed, so the `break` in the `default` block won't be executed.

The code after `default` is only executed if none of the explicit cases match, or the case before `default` is chosen and there's no `break` before `default` (so it falls through).

The `default:` case is usually written last by convention, so a `break` is not normally needed there. The warning in the tutorial is just a reminder that if you put `default:` earlier, the rule that you continue into the next case when there's no `break` still applies; there's nothing special about the `default` rule that would prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

From that [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) you can also read:

> The `default` keyword specifies the code to run if there is **NO CASE** match.

So for example, if defined at the beginning, and there is a `case` match, the code associated with that match will be executed, and not the code associated with the default block, example:

```js
function test(n)
{
    let res;

    switch (n)
    {
        default: 
            res = "default";
            break;
        case 1:
            res = "Case 1";
            break; 
        case 0:
            res = "Case 2";
     }

     return res;
}

console.log(test(1), test(0), test(9));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

As you can see, `default` block is only executed if there is no match (like on `test(9)`). Now, on relation to this:

> *If `default` is not the last case in the `switch` block, remember to end the `default` case with a `break`.*

You can read next warning:

> **Note**: If you omit the `break` statement, the **next** case will be executed even if the evaluation does not match the case.

So, for example, if we omit the `break` statement on the previous example, we are not going to get the expected `default` string for default cases, instead we are going to get string `Case 1`:

```js
function test(n)
{
    let res;

    switch (n)
    {
        default: 
            res = "default";
        case 1:
            res = "Case 1";
            break; 
        case 0:
            res = "Case 2";
     }

     return res;
}

console.log(test(1), test(0), test(9), test(99));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is specified in [ECMA-262, 13.12.9 Runtime Semantics: CaseBlockEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-caseblockevaluation) (that's the definition of JavaScript).

Unfortunately that specification is a bit hard to read, but it boils down to the following: To execute a switch statement, try the `case` clauses before `default`, if any; then try the `case` clauses after `default`, if any; and only if none of them match, execute the `default` part. It doesn't matter where the `default` is located.